# Can I change the mailer for Mercurial Notify?

Tags: mercurial

The default email that I get is quite "uninspired". We were using SVN Notify and it was sending HTML emails that uses a bit of color and made it much easier to read. The default Mercurial one sends a wall of text. I am trying to encourage the developers to read the emails but if they look like that they are less likely to.

Is there anything else that I can hook in?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same desire to have coloured HTML emails, like SVN used to do, and I found a little script from the Linux Journals: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-diff-output-colorized-html to convert diff outputs to colorized HTML.

With this script you can simply set a server hook of the type:

```
changegroup.notify = notify.sh
```

and in `notify.sh`, you need to call the `diff2html.sh` script, e.g.,

```
SUBJECT="[HG `echo $REPO | cut -d/ -f5-` Push] $(hg log -r $HG_NODE --template '{author|person}: {desc|firstline|strip}')"
hg log -vCpr $HG_NODE --style changelog | $HOME/bin/diff2html.sh | mailx -a "From: $FROM" -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" -a "Content-type: text/html;" -s "$SUBJECT" $ADDRESSES
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Another solution consists in using, instead of diff2html, the pygmentize command line tool:

" ... | pygmentize -l diff -f html -O full | ... "

that comes with the *python-pygments* highlighting package.

Answer (score 0):

The `notify` extension, like other parts of Mercurial, does support templating using hg's built-in templating engine. From a cursory glance, it doesn't look like it supports HTML email, though.